# Python 3.4, Finding the Median of the List

Tags: python-3.x

```
def median(L):

length = len(L)

L.sort()
print 'List = ', L

if (length % 2 == 1):       #Length is odd

    index = math.ceil(length / 2)
    index = int(index)

    for i in range(0, length + 1):
        if i  == index:
            print 'Median = ', L[i]
            print 'Median = %.2f' % (L[i])
            return L[i]

elif (length % 2 == 0):                 #Length is even

    index = math.floor(length / 2)
    lower = int(index) - 1
    upper = int(index)

    print L[lower]
    print L[upper]

    median = ((L[upper] + L[lower]) / 2)
    median = float(median)
    print 'Median = %.2f' % (median)
    return median
```

median(L)

Python 3.4

Suppose I use this list
L = [98,75,92,87,89,90,92,87]

When I sort the list and find the two middle numbers, I get 89 and 90...however, I try to take the average of these two numbers

median = ((L[upper] + L[lower]) / 2)

and it returns the number 89.00 instead of 89.50

any idea how to solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the two numbers, L[upper] and L[lower] to float by doing `float(L[upper])+float(L[lower])`